# Issue in Android HTTPS Basic Authentication

Tags: java, android, http, ssl, https

I have been using the EasySSLSocketFactory and EasyX509TrustManager to connect to a HTTPS RESTfull service with HTTPS Basic Authentication.

The code for both of these classes are as follows :

EasySSLSocketFactory :

```
/*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 * software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 * "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;

import org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.LayeredSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

/**
 * This socket factory will create ssl socket that accepts self signed
 * certificate
 * 
 * @author olamy
 * @version $Id: EasySSLSocketFactory.java 765355 2009-04-15 20:59:07Z evenisse
 *          $
 * @since 1.2.3
 */
public class EasySSLSocketFactory implements LayeredSocketFactory {

    private SSLContext sslcontext = null;

    private static SSLContext createEasySSLContext() throws IOException {
        try {
            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            context.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new EasyX509TrustManager(
                    null) }, null);
            return context;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private SSLContext getSSLContext() throws IOException {
        if (this.sslcontext == null) {
            this.sslcontext = createEasySSLContext();
        }
        return this.sslcontext;
    }

    /**
     * @see org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory#connectSocket(java.net.Socket,
     *      java.lang.String, int, java.net.InetAddress, int,
     *      org.apache.http.params.HttpParams)
     */
    public Socket connectSocket(Socket sock, String host, int port,
            InetAddress localAddress, int localPort, HttpParams params)
            throws IOException, UnknownHostException, ConnectTimeoutException {
        int connTimeout = HttpConnectionParams.getConnectionTimeout(params);
        int soTimeout = HttpConnectionParams.getSoTimeout(params);

        InetSocketAddress remoteAddress = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
        SSLSocket sslsock = (SSLSocket) ((sock != null) ? sock : createSocket());

        if ((localAddress != null) || (localPort > 0)) {
            // we need to bind explicitly
            if (localPort < 0) {
                localPort = 0; // indicates "any"
            }
            InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress(localAddress,
                    localPort);
            sslsock.bind(isa);
        }

        sslsock.connect(remoteAddress, connTimeout);
        sslsock.setSoTimeout(soTimeout);
        return sslsock;

    }

    /**
     * @see org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory#createSocket()
     */
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return getSSLContext().getSocketFactory().createSocket();
    }




    /**
     * @see org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory#isSecure(java.net.Socket)
     */
    public boolean isSecure(Socket socket) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @see org.apache.http.conn.scheme.LayeredSocketFactory#createSocket(java.net.Socket,
     *      java.lang.String, int, boolean)
     */
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port,
            boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return getSSLContext().getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host,
                port, autoClose);
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------
    // javadoc in org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory says :
    // Both Object.equals() and Object.hashCode() must be overridden
    // for the correct operation of some connection managers
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return ((obj != null) && obj.getClass().equals(
                EasySSLSocketFactory.class));
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return EasySSLSocketFactory.class.hashCode();
    }

}
```

EasyX509TrustManager:

```
/*
 * ====================================================================
 *
 *  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 *  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 *  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 *  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 *  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 *  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 *  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 *  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 *  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 *  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 *  limitations under the License.
 * ====================================================================
 *
 * This software consists of voluntary contributions made by many
 * individuals on behalf of the Apache Software Foundation.  For more
 * information on the Apache Software Foundation, please see
 * <http://www.apache.org/>.
 *
 */



import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log; 
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

/**
 * <p>
 * EasyX509TrustManager unlike default {@link X509TrustManager} accepts 
 * self-signed certificates. 
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * This trust manager SHOULD NOT be used for productive systems 
 * due to security reasons, unless it is a concious decision and 
 * you are perfectly aware of security implications of accepting 
 * self-signed certificates
 * </p>
 * 
 * @author <a href="mailto:adrian.sutton@ephox.com">Adrian Sutton</a>
 * @author <a href="mailto:oleg@ural.ru">Oleg Kalnichevski</a>
 * 
 * <p>
 * DISCLAIMER: HttpClient developers DO NOT actively support this component.
 * The component is provided as a reference material, which may be inappropriate
 * for use without additional customization.
 * </p>
 */

public class EasyX509TrustManager implements X509TrustManager
{
    private X509TrustManager standardTrustManager = null;

    /** Log object for this class. */
    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(EasyX509TrustManager.class);

    /**
     * Constructor for EasyX509TrustManager.
     */
    public EasyX509TrustManager(KeyStore keystore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {
        super();
        TrustManagerFactory factory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        factory.init(keystore);
        TrustManager[] trustmanagers = factory.getTrustManagers();
        if (trustmanagers.length == 0) {
            throw new NoSuchAlgorithmException("no trust manager found");
        }
        this.standardTrustManager = (X509TrustManager)trustmanagers[0];
    }

    /**
     * @see javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager#checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[],String authType)
     */
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certificates,String authType) throws CertificateException {
        standardTrustManager.checkClientTrusted(certificates,authType);
    }

    /**
     * @see javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager#checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[],String authType)
     */
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certificates,String authType) throws CertificateException {
        if ((certificates != null) && LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOG.debug("Server certificate chain:");
            for (int i = 0; i < certificates.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("X509Certificate[" + i + "]=" + certificates[i]);
            }
        }
        if ((certificates != null) && (certificates.length == 1)) {
            certificates[0].checkValidity();
        } else {
            standardTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(certificates,authType);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager#getAcceptedIssuers()
     */
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return this.standardTrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();
    }
}
```

Main Class is:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        client.getConnectionManager()
                .getSchemeRegistry()
                .register(
                        new Scheme("https", 6443, new AnotherSSLScoketFactory()));

        HttpPost request = new HttpPost();

        request.setHeader(new BasicScheme()
                .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordCredentials(
                        "username", "pass"), request));


        request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");

        request.setURI(new URI(
                "MYURI"));

        request.setEntity(new StringEntity("--SomeData---"));

        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            System.out.println("Response Code "
                    + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        } finally {
            client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
```

This return me a Exception as follows :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received close_notify during handshake
    at com.hp.ssl.easy.Test.main(Test.java:69)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received close_notify during handshake
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:131)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flush(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.flush(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:102)
    at org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity.writeTo(StringEntity.java:122)
    at org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper.writeTo(HttpEntityWrapper.java:96)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper$EntityWrapper.writeTo(EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:120)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:263)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.sendRequestEntity(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:227)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:255)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:645)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:464)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
    at com.hp.ssl.easy.Test.main(Test.java:65)
```

Have been trying to resolve this from a week, havent made much progress. Can anyone help me understand whats the mistake i am doing. My HTTP SSL knowledge is pretty basic and all the code i got from the internet.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Errol

Comment: Is the server using a self-signed certificate by any chance?

Comment: yep... its a self signed certificate.. i have no issues with CA signed certificates...

Comment: @ Errol:The exception you post seems to indicate that the interface you are trying to talk to is down.Are you sure it is up?

Comment: I dont know what you mean with the word Interface. But if you are taking about the RestService i can access the same in Soap UI and alos using Apache Commons 3.X i am able to perform the request after accepting the Self Signed Certificate.